# .show and .hide every <div>

Tags: jquery, html, settimeout

```
$("div.item").hide(); 
var i=0;
function transition() {

    $("div.item").eq(i).show();

    setTimeout(function() { $("div.item").eq(i).hide() }, 2000);
    i++;            
}

setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

I want my code to hide every div element on loading and afterwards showing each one (right after each other) for 2000ms before hiding it again.

Currently the div's are shown after each other but not hidden again - they are lined up.

Comment: Why can't you just hide the prev before you show the current without `setTimeout`?

Comment: The `i` variable is increased to the next item before the `setTimeout` is called, so you are hiding the next item, then immediately showing it again.

Comment: I replaced "i++" with "setTimeout(function() { i++ }, 2001);" and it seems to work, bu imho that does not seem to be elegant ... any suggestions on how to hide the prev before showing the current one without setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at what your code is doing (more or less...)

```
// hide all items
$("div.item").hide(); 
// setup a global var
var i=0;


function transition() {
    // on first loop show item 0
    $("div.item").eq(i).show();

    // do some code _later_
    setTimeout(function() { _later_ }, 2000);

    // point to the next item
    i++;    
}

// repeat the above
setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

which can be broken down to:

- i = 0
- show 0
- i = 1
- wait 2s
- hide 1
- show 1
- i = 2

etc

The setTimeout runs just before the setInterval kicks in

---

You can fix this by keeping a copy of `i`:

```js
$("div").hide();
var i = 0;


function transition() {
  $("div").eq(i).show();

  // take a local copy of i so that when i changes below, j keeps the old value
  let j = i;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").eq(j).hide()
  }, 200);

  i++;
  if (i>=$("div").length-1) i = 0;
}

setInterval(transition, 200);
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

---

As an extra, as you'll see from the snippet, the two setTimeout/setIntervals don't run smoothly together and you get a very flickery output (maybe that's the desired output?).

If you don't want this flicker, then you can add the `.hide()` call directly inside `transition()` and jquery/the DOM will have the effect of actioning both at the same time.

```js
$("div").hide();
var i = 0;

function transition() {
  $("div").eq(i).hide();

  i++;
  if (i>=$("div").length-1) i = 0;

  $("div").eq(i).show();
}

setInterval(transition, 200);
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need without changing your code much.
Please specify if need something else.

```js
$("div.item").hide();
var i = 0;

function transition() {
$("div.item").eq(i).show(); {
    $("div.item").eq(i - 1).hide()
}
i++;
}
setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

```css
.item {
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     text-align: center;
     left: 0;
     top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" style="background-color: red;">1</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: cyan;">2</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: yellow;">3</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: green;">4</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: pink;">5</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: gray;">6</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: lightgreen;">7</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: skyblue;">8</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: brown;">9</div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: bisque;">10</div>
```